# Python lambda side effect

Tags: python

I am looking at [T.Scholak's gist](https://gist.github.com/tscholak/fa9953810456429458db769d9031c53c)

I will reproduce with Jupyter

```
def side_effecty_id(x):
        print(x)
        return x
```

Let's consider

```
lambdas_0 = tuple((lambda x: x >= side_effecty_id(i)) for i in range(10))
tuple(l(5) for l in lambdas_0)
```

Result

```
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
```

While

```
lambdas_1 = tuple((lambda i: lambda x: x >= side_effecty_id(i))(i) for i in range(10))
tuple(l(5) for l in lambdas_1)
```

Gives

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
(True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False)
```

I regard this as very good example. 
Why do we need double lambdas?
I have compared lambdas_0 and lambdas_1

```
<function __main__.<genexpr>.<lambda>(x)>
```

and

```
<function __main__.<genexpr>.<lambda>.<locals>.<lambda>(x)>,
```

What does `<locals>` denote?

Comment: `<locals>` refers to the local scope of a function. In this case, the lambda function. In other words, it means that the `lambda x` has been defined in a function.